# Android App to Another Platforms

Tags: android

I wrote an Android app with about 11.000 lines code. I need to port the app to Windows, Mac OS and other platforms as well, but I don't have the time and knowledge to do so. Is there a way to covert the Android app normal Java App that will run under Windows and Mac OS X without starting a ***very*** slow Android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another solution. I'm pretty sure that there isn't any solution now, having the whole code written for Android.
If from the beginning you knew this, maybe you would developed your application using a tool like [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)  that allows you to build cross-platform native applications. But it has an own syntax, and transforming now your code from Java to Objective-C or C#.

Android is not just some Java Libraries, it is an operating system, so you can't just port your "libraries" and run them on MacOS or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Android is a standalone operating system and apps written for Android SDK can only run on Android OS.

There are projects that enable you to run whole Android OS inside a virtual machine: http://www.android-x86.org/

Answer (score 0):

From the app that you have right now, there is no way to do it, but you could choose from a cross-platform development tools or something like that and make the app again.

You might find some cross-platforms engines here:
http://www.toolsjournal.com/tools-world/item/157-10-of-best-cross-platform-mobile-development-tools

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (depends on the type of app it is) you could create one app in html5 you can check this link for explanations:
http://blog.farreachinc.com/2011/08/25/html5-will-native-apps-obsolete/
Html5 can be used in many platforms.

I think you can reuse some of the code for java based mobile phones. Mac OS is developped in objective C so no.